# Put data from Worksheet into Taskpane

Tags: excel, office-js, office-addins

I've got a taskpane and one of the fields I'd like to fill out from the worksheet.

How can I access data from Worksheets during Office Taskpane startup?

Example:

```
Office.onReady(function (info) {

    const range = context.workbook.getSelectedRange();

    // Read the range address
    range.load("address");

    // Update the fill color
    range.format.fill.color = "yellow";

})
```

gives error `Context` is undefined.

How can I load some data and send it up to the Taskpane on launch?

A simple example is, I have a Dropdown which I'd like to populate with column letters, but only from the `usedrange`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to use the `Excel.RequestContext` object. You need to get a reference to it before you call it. The recommended way to do this is to call `Excel.run`. It will automatically create the `context` object and pass it to the callback. Here's an example.

```
await Excel.run(async (context) => {
  var selectedRange = context.workbook.getSelectedRange();
  selectedRange.load('address');
  await context.sync();
  console.log('The selected range is: ' + selectedRange.address);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

[@RickKirkham answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71301747/5079799) helped point me in the correct direction. I had to add `async` to the main func and then I was able to do what was needed after `Excel.Run`

Eg:

```
Office.onReady(async function (info) {
    await Excel.run(async (context) => {
        var ws = context.workbook.worksheets.getActiveWorksheet()
        var rng = ws.getRange("A1")
        rng.load(["values"]);
        await context.sync();
        Input_Box_Client_Code.defaults.Value = rng.values[0][0];
        Init_InputBoxes(InputBoxs_ArrOfObjs);
    });
})
```